# Convert box to matrix

Tags: 3d, mathematics, sphere, projection-matrix

I have a box (non-rectangular cuboid?) and would like to convert it to a matrix such that when a point inside the box is multiplied by the matrix, a vector is returned that describes the relative position inside the box (very similar in regard to a camera's view and projection matrix)

The difference between this box and a camera frustum, is that the box vertices are defined by the points intersecting 4 rays from the center of two concentric spheres.

What's the formula for creating such a matrix?

Comment: Could you provide some visualisation? By "non-rectangular cuboid" do you mean a cube?

Comment: @Mars By non-rectangular cuboid I mean a six-sided convex polygon defined by 8 points (just like a cube) except that the faces are not rectangles. In this case, the faces should be trapezoids I think.